# Reading Rabbit MQ From LogStash (ELK Instance)

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash

I have 2 servers, one RabbitMQ, and one ELK server.
Both are independently running as they should. My ELK instance receives input messages from several sources across my network, but both servers are in the same internal network.

I am trying to make LogStash read from RabbitMQ, to get any log messages i pushed into there.

Here's my logstash conf.d file:

```
input{
    rabbitmq {
        host => "1.66.66.66"
        queue => "logs"
        durable => true
        exchange => "event.log"
        threads => 1
        prefetch_count => 50
        port => 5672
        user => "elk"
        password => "*******"
    }
}
filter{
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["1.66.66.1:9200"]
        sniffing => false
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }
}
```

After i run a config test ($ sudo service logstash configtest)
if get: ConfigTest OK

So this seems good.
But then when it runs i get the following error in my "/var/log/logstash/logstash.log" file:

```
{:timestamp=>"2017-06-15T10:28:18.727000-0400", :message=>"Connection refused (Connection refused)", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:256:in `call_once'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:153:in `code'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:84:in `perform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:257:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:67:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/sniffer.rb:32:in `hosts'", "org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:147:in `timeout'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/sniffer.rb:31:in `hosts'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:79:in `reload_connections!'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:72:in `sniff!'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:60:in `start_sniffing!'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:60:in `start_sniffing!'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1479:in `loop'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:59:in `start_sniffing!'"], :level=>:error}
```

If, from my ELK server do:

```
curl -X GET http://1.66.66.1:9200
```

I get the proper response:

```
{
  "name" : "Hera",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "-NmCwDk_RA2qzTwWlNNizQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.4.5",
    "build_hash" : "c849dd13904f53e63e88efc33b2ceeda0b6a1276",
    "build_timestamp" : "2017-04-24T16:18:17Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

If you know anything i can try, that would be much appreciated, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on both servers. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `curl -X GET http://1.66.66.1:9200` from your Logstash server?

Comment: My logstash server is the ELK server, so yes, i did that from that server, thanks!